# ZXing Xcode 4.2 iOS compiling error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, zxing

I'm trying to include ZxingWidget to my project. I copied the ZXingWidget.xcodeproj to my project,added ZXingWidget in “Target Dependencies” and libZXingWidget.a to “Link Binary With Libraries" then start compiling but there are fews apple LLVM compiler3.0 error.

I tried with a new project and follow the steps and it work properly. I'm not sure is there any problem with the setting of my current project. Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try highlighting the first error and doing a right-click "reveal in log" (or something like that). It should open the full/long error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to copy ZXingWidget.xcodeproj to your project.

- Drag ZXingWidget.xcodeproj and drop it onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files" sidebar.
- Make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project".

After you link ZXingWidget library and add the dependency, you should also add header search path in your project setting:

1. Select the build setting of your project target
2. Add the relative path from your project's directory to the  `zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes` directory. remember to enable the "recursive path".
3. Add zxing cpp headers to your headers search path, add the relative directory path of `cpp/core/src/`, and remember not to enable "recursive path".

Import frameworks of "Link Libraries with Binary" in your project target:

- AVFoundation
- AudioToolbox
- CoreVideo
- CoreMedia
- libiconv
- AddressBook
- AddressBookUI

Then import `<ZXingWidgetController.h>` and `<QRCodeReader.h>` in your target view controller, remember to edit the suffix ".m" to ".mm".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, thnx @bradley the thing is you gotta check your paths...

**Here’s my example:**

My current project path:

> ~/Dropbox/Tesis Project/Celedex

My current library ZXing:

> ~/Dropbox/Tesis Project/ZXingWidget

**So the header search paths look like this:**

> ../ZXingWidget/Classes (recursive)
>
> ../../cpp/core/src (non-recursive)

Good luck, and best wishes.